# Total multiple tables Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I am attempting to sum multiple tables' subtotals together to create a grand total. I've found a method to do so by naming the table and and then using =sum(tableName[columnName]). Therefore I could just add several of them together to achieve my result.

However, when I look at the pre-loaded templates, there is one called Family Monthly Budget where they have a total table that sums multiple tables showing only a single entry =totalExpenseProjected. When I click that cell, it highlights as a formula, but gives no indication as to how its calculated and I cannot recreate it using my own spreadsheet.

[image]

Can anyone offer insight on how to use the microsoft method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the `Formulas->Name Manager` you will see this named range is really a mess of a `SUM` formula:

```
=SUM(Actual1,Actual2,Actual3,Actual4,Actual5,Actual6,Actual7,Actual8,Actual9,Actual10,Actual11,Actual12,Actual13)
```

That `SUM` is using other named ranges.  A sample of the formula in `Actual1` is:

```
=Housing[[#Totals],[Actual]]
```

It then repeats that for the other 12 `Actual` references.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew it seemed a bit too simple.